# Getting number of xml nodes containing certain value in php and xml

Tags: php, xml, count, nodes

Hi I am trying to get the count for all nodes with certain content or value. In this case I have an xml as so:

```
<hotel>
<city>Cancun</city>
<postalCode>77500</postalCode>
<countryCode>MX</countryCode>
<airportCode>CUN</airportCode>
<supplierType>E</supplierType>
<propertyCategory>1</propertyCategory>
<hotelRating>4.0</hotelRating>
<confidenceRating>52</confidenceRating>
</hotel>
```

I need to find all hotelRating with the value of 4 and count how many there are in my xml list. I have no idea of how to do this with php. If anyone can help me with this I would appreciate it so much!!

By the way I have already connected the xml file as follows and am able to get data and send data.

```
$post_string= 'type=xml&cid=222&minorRev=14&apiKey=222&locale='.$userLocale.'&currencyCode='.$userCurr.'&customerIpAddress='.$userIp.'&customerUserAgent='.$userAgent.'&xml=<HotelListRequest><destinationId>'.$destinationId.'</destinationId><arrivalDate>'.$arriving.'</arrivalDate><departureDate>'.$departing.'</departureDate><RoomGroup>'.$xmlQuery.'</RoomGroup><supplierCacheTolerance>MED_ENHANCED</supplierCacheTolerance></HotelListRequest> ';
//Relative path to the file with $_POST parsing
$path = "http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list"; 
$ch = curl_init($path); 
$fp = fopen('xml/data.xml','w');
//Send the data to the file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/xml')); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
$val = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);//Close curl session
fclose($fp); //Close file overwrite
$data = simplexml_load_file('xml/data.xml');
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($data->hotel as $hotel)
{
    if ($hotel->hotelRating == '4.0')
    {
        //  hotel with 4.0 rating found
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = $data->xpath("count(\"//hotel[hotelRating= '4.0']\")");
```

Will give you the count of hotels where hotelrating = 4.0.